# filtering index Pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a frame like this

```
frame=pd.DataFrame({'Team':['USA','GER','CAN','USA','GER','CAN'],
                'MOV':[-5,2,0,0,3,4]})
```

I can do a groupby to get the mean 'MOV' for each team

```
print (frame.groupby('Team')['MOV'].mean())
```

which outputs

```
 Team
 CAN    2.0
 GER    2.5
 USA   -2.5
 Name: MOV, dtype: float64
```

I want to return a list or array of the teams with a positive 'MOV'.  In this case 'GER' and 'CAN'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
means = frame.groupby('Team')['MOV'].mean()

print (list(means[means > 0].index))
```

`means` is a series which you can then filter by taking all values in that series that are greater than 0.  Then take the index of that filtered series (which will contain the country names) and print it as a list.